# How do I access a CD drive on a Linux machine from my Mac?

Tags: network, unix, optical-drive

I used this question: https://superuser.com/questions/316745/how-to-access-a-cd-dvd-drive-over-the-network to install nbd-server on my linux machine and share the CD drive.

But installing nbd-client on my Mac doesn't appear to be possible. Can't find it in homebrew.

How can I access the CD in that drive from my Mac?

Comment: I know your question says *installing nbd-client on my Mac doesn't appear to be possible*, but can you edit it to provide additional details on what you've actually tried and with what results?

Comment: I tried to install with homebrew, like I said. Apt-get isn't on mac, so that's not an option. I can't find any instructions for installing it on a mac on the web.

Comment: Chepe I don't get what you mean by that... the CD drive is on a linux machine

Comment: @jcollum do you want to share drive *from* Linux *to* macOS?

Comment: According to your post: you Want to install nbd-client in macOS to get access to your CD Drive, I will use Samba on Linux Side https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273743/macos-sierra-doesnt-discover-devices-on-lan to get access from macOS to any Folder on Linux side

Comment: Is nbd-server in home brew yet?